# C#, Windows Forms, Como implementar dos ComboxBoxes en un Formulario pero CON EL MISMO datasource?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017

tengo en un formulario dos comboboxes con un mismo datasource:

```
private void LlenarCbosCatalogo()
{
    AuxiliaresCatalogoCtaList = CatalogoCuentaLN.ObtenerAuxiliares();

    cboAuxiliar.ValueMember = "IdCatalogoCuenta";
    cboAuxiliar.DisplayMember = "NombreCompleto";
    cboAuxiliar.DataSource = AuxiliaresCatalogoCtaList;

    cboPrima.ValueMember = "IdCatalogoCuenta";
    cboPrima.DisplayMember = "NombreCompleto";
    cboPrima.DataSource = AuxiliaresCatalogoCtaList;
}
```

[image: FormularioCuenta]

**Pero** cuando selecciono un item del primer combo, también se autoselecciona en el segundo.

Como hacer para evitar éste comportamiento?

Comment: No se puede evitar. Lo que debes hacer es una copia de `AuxiliaresCatalogoCtaList` y usar la copia como datasource

Comment: Es un DataSet , DataTable o List?

Comment: una Lista: AuxiliaresCatalogoCtaList

Comment: Puedes agregar el método `CatalogoCuentaLN.ObtenerAuxiliares()`? y la declaración de `AuxiliaresCatalogoCtaList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que yo haria es crear un Datatable para cada Combobox.
es decir create un metodo que transforme tu lista en un data table. para haci asignarsela a tu datasource del combobo.

Este es un ejemplo de como comnvertir una lista de tipo string a un data table.
espero haberte ayudado.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Example list.
            List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();
            list.Add(new string[] { "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3" });
            list.Add(new string[] { "Row 2", "Row 2" });
            list.Add(new string[] { "Row 3" });

            // Convert to DataTable.
            DataTable dtAuxiliar= ConvertListToDataTable(list);
            DataTable dtPrima= ConvertListToDataTable(list);           

            cboAuxiliar.ValueMember = "IdCatalogoCuenta";
            cboAuxiliar.DisplayMember = "NombreCompleto";
            cboAuxiliar.DataSource = dtAuxiliar;

            cboPrima.ValueMember = "IdCatalogoCuenta";
            cboPrima.DisplayMember = "NombreCompleto";
            cboPrima.DataSource = dtPrima;
        }
 static DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(List<string[]> list)
        {
            // New table.
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            // Get max columns.
            int columns = 0;
            foreach (var array in list)
            {
                if (array.Length > columns)
                {
                    columns = array.Length;
                }
            }

            // Add columns.
            for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
            {
                table.Columns.Add();
            }

            // Add rows.
            foreach (var array in list)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(array);
            }

            return table;
        }
    }
}
```

otra seria crear una variable para cada source de los combobox..

```
private void LlenarCbosCatalogo()
{
    var AuxiliarList = CatalogoCuentaLN.ObtenerAuxiliares();
    var PrimaList = CatalogoCuentaLN.ObtenerAuxiliares();

    cboAuxiliar.ValueMember = "IdCatalogoCuenta";
    cboAuxiliar.DisplayMember = "NombreCompleto";
    cboAuxiliar.DataSource = AuxiliarList.toList(); 

    cboPrima.ValueMember = "IdCatalogoCuenta";
    cboPrima.DisplayMember = "NombreCompleto";
    cboPrima.DataSource = PrimaList.toList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo haces con un `DataSet` o un `DataTable` puedes usar `Copy()` te copiara la estructura y la información a un nuevo elemento:

```
private void LlenarCbosCatalogo()
{
    AuxiliaresCatalogoCtaList = CatalogoCuentaLN.ObtenerAuxiliares();
    cboAuxiliar.ValueMember = "IdCatalogoCuenta";
    cboAuxiliar.DisplayMember = "NombreCompleto";
    cboAuxiliar.DataSource = AuxiliaresCatalogoCtaList;
    cboPrima.ValueMember = "IdCatalogoCuenta";
    cboPrima.DisplayMember = "NombreCompleto";
    cboPrima.DataSource = AuxiliaresCatalogoCtaList.Copy();
}
```

Si usas `List` solo crea una lista nueva y usas `AddRange()` para crear una copia de la lista:

```
private void LlenarCbosCatalogo()
{
    AuxiliaresCatalogoCtaList = CatalogoCuentaLN.ObtenerAuxiliares();
    List<AuxiliaresCatalogo> AuxiliaresCatalogoCtaList2 = new List<AuxiliaresCatalogo>().AddRange(AuxiliaresCatalogoCtaList);

    cboAuxiliar.ValueMember = "IdCatalogoCuenta";
    cboAuxiliar.DisplayMember = "NombreCompleto";
    cboAuxiliar.DataSource = AuxiliaresCatalogoCtaList;

    cboPrima.ValueMember = "IdCatalogoCuenta";
    cboPrima.DisplayMember = "NombreCompleto";
    cboPrima.DataSource = AuxiliaresCatalogoCtaList2;
}
```